# Error communication in I2C in PIC32

Tags: pic, i2c, rtc

**Duplicate question was also asked by me and the current question has different code**

I have a `PIC32 starter kit` and I am making `I2C` communication with `DS1307 RTC`. I have used the functions for `I2C Communiation` described in this [document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32bitPeripheralLibraryGuide.pdf) page no- 221. I am using MPLAB 8 with watch window opened and added all the register of I2C in watch window, so that when I debug my code, I can see which register has what value. Following is my code:

```
#include <plib.h>

#define SYSTEM_FREQUENCY            72000000L
#pragma config FNOSC = PRIPLL       //Primary Osc w/PLL (XT+,HS+,EC+PLL)
#pragma config POSCMOD = HS         //HS osc mode 
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_18     //PLL Multiplier 18x Multiplier 
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2     //PLL Input Divider 2x Divider 
#pragma config FPBDIV = DIV_1       //Peripheral Clock Divisor: Pb_Clk is Sys_Clk/2
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1     //System PLL Output Clock Divider: PLL Divide by 1
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF         //WatchDog Timer

#define CCLK  (60000000)
#define PBCLK (CCLK/8)

#define Fsck 375000
#define BRG_VAL (PBCLK/2/Fsck)

int main()
{
  mOSCSetPBDIV (OSC_PB_DIV_8);

  OpenI2C1( I2C_EN, BRG_VAL );


  //*********INIT I2C************// 
  StartI2C1();
  IdleI2C1();    //This function generates Wait condition until I2C bus is Idle.
  MasterWriteI2C1(0xD0);  //Address of DS1307
  MasterWriteI2C1(0x07);
  MasterWriteI2C1(0x00);
  AckI2C1();    
  StopI2C1();
  IdleI2C1();
  //*********INIT I2C END**********//


  //**********SET DATE**********//  
  int i=5, j =5, k =5;
  StartI2C1();
  IdleI2C1();
  MasterWriteI2C1(0xD0);
  MasterWriteI2C1(0x04);
  i = MasterWriteI2C1(0x19);
  j = MasterWriteI2C1(0x10);
  k = MasterWriteI2C1(0x09);
  AckI2C1();        
  StopI2C1();
  IdleI2C1();
  //*********SET DATE END*********//


  //**********GET DATE************//
  if(I2C1STATbits.RBF == 1)   //if data is available
  {
   StartI2C1();
   IdleI2C1();
   MasterWriteI2C1(0xD0);
   AckI2C1();   
   IdleI2C1();
   StopI2C1();
   IdleI2C1();

   unsigned char val1 = 5;
   unsigned char val2 = 5;
   unsigned char val3 = 5;
   StartI2C1();                
    MasterWriteI2C1(0xD1);      
   val1 = MasterReadI2C1();
   val2 = MasterReadI2C1();
   val3 = MasterReadI2C1();
   AckI2C1();   

   StopI2C1();
   IdleI2C1();
}
if(I2C1STATbits.RBF == 0)    //if data is not available
{

}
return 0;
}
```

For the time being I am just trying to set date and read it back.

1) My first problem is that, when I start debugging, in `INIT I2C` after `IdleI2C1();`     I2C1STAT   (register which gives the status of I2C ) gives value `0x400` which means 10th bit is 1 and if we look into the bits of this register then it says:

```
bit 10:
  BCL: Master Bus Collision Detect bit
  Cleared when the I2C module is disabled (ON = 0).
  1 =A bus collision has been detected during a master operation
  0 =No collision has been detected
```

So this means that collision has been detected. But i havent send anything then why it is saying that collision has been detected.?

2) `MasterWrite()` function is running properly, because when ever this command is executed, i can see the change in I2C1TRN register(this displays the transmitted data) and the values of i j k changes to 0 because `MasterWrite()` returns 0 whenever the data is transmitted successfully. But when my control reaches the `GetDate` it doesnt enter because no data is available. So my second question is that when my data is transmitted successfully, why I am not getting any data back??

Any Pic experts please help me with I2C communication. Thanks!

Comment: yeah thats my question but I have changed the code.

Comment: Do you have pull-ups on both lines for sure?  If your SDA line is not pulled high properly, the PIC would see that as a bus collision.

Comment: No I dont have pull up resistor. Looks like I'll have to make my own circuit for this. can you tell me schematic for DS1307. I have found this circuit: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/RTC-Module.v14.pdf . Is it good enough for communication

Comment: Adding pull-up resistors is a necessity in I2C communication. Their values are critical. I tried DS1307 + AVR 16Mhz does not work properly with 10k, works with 1k8 ohm

Comment: You should have edited your original question rather than starting a new one.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have external pull-up resistors as mentioned in the comments, you can try to enable the internal pull-ups - it's hard to find an actual value on them, but if the [quoted](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61156H.pdf#page=368) 50µA in the data sheet are related to the pull-ups they would be around \$66k\Omega\$. Those values are a bit high, but with a slow I²C clock they should be fine. Outside of the [official I²C specification](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf), so no guarantee they will work, have a look at page 55.

To enable those you can use the change notification functions of the peripheral library ([here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32bitPeripheralLibraryGuide.pdf#page=123)) on the SDA and SCL pins. I'm not 100% sure if that will work (not a PIC expert), the description of the I²C module sounds like it could override all I/O pin settings ([here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61116F.pdf#page=17)):

> Enabling I 2 C I/O
>
> Two pins are used for bus operation: the SCLx pin, which is the clock, and the SDAx pin, which
> is the data. When the I 2 C module is enabled, assuming no other module with higher priority has
> control, the module will assume control of the SDAx and SCLx pins. The module software need
> not be concerned with the state of the port I/O of the pins, the module overrides, the port state,
> and direction. At initialization, the pins are tri-state (released).

Even if that works, putting external pull-up resistors is recommended as you can change the value if your I²C bus grows larger or you have noise issues.

The [schematic](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/RTC-Module.v14.pdf) you posted in your comment is fine (note: C1 is used as a decoupling capacitor for the RTC supply pin, and should be placed as closely to the pin as possible). I wonder what kind of connection / schematic you used until now.

Comment: Please help me improve my answer by pointing out wrong parts instead of just downvoting. Thank you.